# adding same 'id' in two tables in sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to give same id in 2 sql table, my code is like below:

```
$field1=$_POST['field1'];
$field2=$_POST['field2'];
$field3=$_POST['field3'];

 $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into employees(name,position,salary) value('$field1','$field2','$field3')");
```

This code takes values from my **HTML** input box and add the values to the table correctly, now i need one more table which will have the same id as the above table(so that i can connect both tables), i tried something like the below code after the first query, but as i am not able to get any condition which will give me the correct id, nothing worked, sample is below

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into employees(name,position,salary,empid) value('$field1','$field2','$field3')");

$query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into date(id) value(select id from employees where)");
```

Can anyone please tell me is there any way to give same id to both tables in sql using php.

Comment: you can use `empid` . Insert the `empid` in both `employees` and `date` table.

Comment: You should invest some time in relation databases. I think you are missing the main point there. You don't need the same id, you only need a field in one of your tables to reference to the other.

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit i know that, but the data in my table will keep on adding, so i need random number in one column to reference one another, but if i generate random numbers its not 100 percent that it will return unique values, so i am trying to use the same id which will be unique

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit how one can join two table without a common value ??

Comment: @Anshu Sharma its not about the joining, he wants to insert them. So he can do a ref.

Comment: Your query is insecure.

Comment: @kingkhankkhan you can use `uniqid()` function and insert the same id in both the tables using insert query. or you can generate two random numbers or alphanumeric value separately and then concatenate them and insert them in table. It will reduce the chances of generating same value.

Comment: @AnshuSharma i have tried that, but i think if we use id , then there is no chance it will be same, so just want to know if i could get that id somehow

Comment: @kingkhankkhan you want auto increamented id or user generated id ? if you use `uniqid()`it will generate a id and then you can insert that id in both table so it will eventually be same.

Comment: @AnshuSharma i need autoincrimented id

Comment: you could set up a `trigger` on the `employees` table that adds a record to the other table. Incidentally `date` is NOT a good name for a table!

Comment: @RamRaider can you show me how to do that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$last_id = $con->insert_id;` for get last inserted ID.

Please try the below code. It's working for you.

```
 $field1 = 'name';
    $field2 = 'position';
    $field3 = '10000';
    $field4 = 'SOF01';

// insert employees data
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO employees (name,position,salary,empid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4);
    $stmt->execute();

// get last insert id
    $last_id = $con->insert_id;

// insert last id in date table
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO date (id) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $last_id);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment and subsequently requested - a `trigger` would seem a good option to deal with the problem as you need only concern yourself with the initial insert - the duplicated ID ( or other fields ) are then handled automatically by the trigger.

Given two basic tables to replicate thse from the question

```
mysql> describe employees;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| position | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| salary   | decimal(10,2)    | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+



mysql> describe date;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| timestamp | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

A simple `trigger` that is bound to the `employees` table and inserts to the `date` table when a new row has been added.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_employee_inserts` AFTER INSERT ON `employees` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    insert into `date` set `id`=new.id;
END
```

To test

```
insert into employees (`name`,`position`,`salary` ) values ( 'Peter', 'Porcupine Pickler', 75000 );
insert into employees (`name`,`position`,`salary` ) values ( 'Roger', 'Rabitt Rustler', 25000 );
insert into employees (`name`,`position`,`salary` ) values ( 'Michael', 'Mouse Mauler', 15000 );

select * from `employees`;
select * from `date`;
```

The result

```
mysql> select * from employees;
+----+---------+-------------------+----------+
| id | name    | position          | salary   |
+----+---------+-------------------+----------+
|  1 | Peter   | Porcupine Pickler | 75000.00 |
|  2 | Roger   | Rabitt Rustler    | 25000.00 |
|  3 | Michael | Mouse Mauler      | 15000.00 |
+----+---------+-------------------+----------+


mysql> select * from date;
+----+---------------------+
| id | timestamp           |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2020-01-16 10:11:15 |
|  2 | 2020-01-16 10:11:15 |
|  3 | 2020-01-16 10:11:15 |
+----+---------------------+
```